# Term for the person working with chocolate

Tags: terminology

What is the term for a person working professionally with chocolates (stuffed chocolates and alike of the finer sort)?

I'm looking for the "title" of such a person in the same manner as the word *confectioner*, which is the broader term for someone skilled in making creative cakes, ice cream courses, stuffed chocolates and decorative sweet things in general.

Comment: Googling for "term for person who works with chocolate" answers this instantly.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: yeah, so?

Comment: @Marthaª So do we welcome general reference questions even in 2016? This question shows zero research effort, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @NVZ: no, we don't welcome general reference questions. Show me a general reference specifically designed to authoritatively answer this type of question. (Hint: Google is designed to help find websites. It is not a general reference resource for any question that would on topic at ELU.)

Comment: I downvoted for the same reason as @DavidRicherby. Even the most cursory research would have identified a suitable answer. Per the downvote script; **"this question does not show any research effort"**

Comment: @Marthaª Well, Google immediately tells you that the answer _might be_ "chocolatier". Even people who don't want to trust Google now have a word they can look up in a dictionary that they do trust. I accept that having to check a dictionary too means that Google isn't "instant", as I originally claimed. However, it does lead you right to the answer.

Comment: @Marthaª yeah, so? OP should do the research first, suggest the words he found and  then ask us for an authoritative answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You're missing the point of the SE network. While some amount of research is advisable, the SE network wants to be a resource that Google can use. Imagine that someone Googles his question, and the first thing he finds is a SE question with no answers and a couple of comments telling them to "Google it". That doesn't really help him. Whether the answer is present on Google or not is irrelevant for this. see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: To see if a general reference could find an answer, I tried searching for "chocolate work" in Wiktionary. The first match which was a profession was [geisha](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/geisha). The hit happened because of an image caption "A geisha at work", and talking about a Finnish chocolate brand called "Geisha". [chocolate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chocolate#Related_terms) mentions chocolatier in the "related terms" section. However, I haven't voted to close.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you are looking for ***[chocolatier](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chocolatier)***:

> - a person who makes or sells chocolate candy

(M-W)

The term is a French one which  has become popular especially from the 80's according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chocolatier&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchocolatier%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Steeven - you may emphasize the technical know-how, by saying "master chocolatier".

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that the question could be refined to include whether the person "'***working***' with chocolate" was '***working***' [Manufacturing it from a scratch..coco beans, adding the cream/milk, and so forth] or is '***working***' in a sales capacity only of handling the made and ready for public consumption product to be delivered in some fashion from say a storefront customer/end user might happen to walk in or in a packaged to order with delivery like a flower and/or candy company might do for Valentine's Day. Secondly, whether the business interest is solely Chocolate; because, if the person "works with chocolate" but with other sweets, even if chocolate is the primary or is found prolifically with each purchase the person would be better defined as a Confectioner. The work environment would commonly be termed as a Confectioner's shop in the business of selling confections also called sweets or candy is sweet food. Also it may be sold along side or in a form like Ice cream, or Taffy, Caramels, hard candies, Hot Fudges, etc. The term varies among English-speaking countries. In general, though, confectionery is divided into two broad and somewhat overlapping categories, bakers' confections and sugar confections. A good reference I found was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confectionery. I hope this proves helpful, edifying or at least satisfactory {like a nice bite of rich chocolate}.

Answer (score 0):

The word I have heard used for someone who works in a Chocolaterie is a [**Pâtissier**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/p%C3%A2tissier), even though title is typically given to pastry chefs, and not artisans working in chocolate in particular.